# CNTK and UserMinibatchSource prefetch

Tags: python, cntk

If I implement an `UserMinibatchSource` in python, will the minibatch data be prefetched when training?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by pre-fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefetching functionality is part of the Deserializer classes in C++. Therefore, prefetching will not be available for custom data unless you write some C++ code.

Comment: I had the same question -- to clarify, I think this means that with a  UserMinibatchSource, the python minibatch preparation code will be run serially, between GPU compute cycles, right? 

It would be super nice if the minibatch prep code could be run in a parallel thread while the GPU is computing... is that technically feasible? I'm not working with image or speech data and the CNTK text format doesn't seem ideal either.